# RSA Modulus prefaced by 0x00

Tags: rsa, public-key-encryption, x509

```
    0:d=0  hl=4 l= 266 cons: SEQUENCE          
    4:d=1  hl=4 l= 257 prim:  INTEGER           :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
  265:d=1  hl=2 l=   3 prim:  INTEGER           :010001

$ echo -n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| wc
      0       1     512
```

Above is an 2048-bit RSA key generated by OpenSSL. Notice it has a "257" length for the modulus field. If you count the hex chars printed for the modulus you see it is appropriately 512=256*2. In the ASN1, there is a 0x00 infront of the modulus. Since the modulus is an integer, this doesn't affect the RSA math. But why is it there? A 0x00 can also be seen in X509 certificates prefixing the public key value. What is the purpose of these extra 0x00?

Answer (score 3):

That's because of ASN.1 coding. As far as I remember, INTEGERs there are signed so when they starts from byte higher than 0x80 they should be treated as negative numbers, that's why they are prefixed with 0x00.

Comment: Looks like you are right about it being ASN1 related. Integers can be negative, using the same format as integers in C. Looks like the extra 0x00 on the front of bit-strings describe the number of unused bits on the end of the string.

Comment: when you see 0x00 infront of an integer in ASN1, its because integers can be negative, so 0x00 infront ensures the sign bit is not set

Comment: when you see it on bit strings like before the public key in a certificate, it describes how many unused BITS are on the end (because you could encode any number of bits, not divisible by 8)